# Understanding String.Format on different systems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to understand why the exact same code deployed on 2 different PC's behaves differently.

In a Unity project in my Update loop I have a simple countdown timer. I start at 25 seconds.

This is my code in Update

```
 _timer -= Time.deltaTime;
 _temp = String.Format("{00:00:00.00}", _timer);
 _temp = _temp.Remove(5, 1).Insert(5, ":");
 _uiText.text = _temp;
```

On my test machine it works properly displaying seconds counting down from 25 as well as 10ths and hundreths ie 00:25:XX

But on my deploy machine instead I see it starting at 5 minutes and seconds are starting at 100!
ie 05:99:XX

Why would it perform differently?

Comment: Time is not a class in .NET and propably not mono either. What is it's definition, particular deltaTime? How are you creating that Time? Are you creating it from a string? What types are those variables? Why are you not using DateTime or Timespan?

Comment: What type is `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: What type are variables `_timer` and `Time.deltaTime` ? Please explain, otherwise your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Float AFAIK. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Comment: @Cristopher, he is using Unity. In it, Time class is defined. And `Time.deltaTime` is `float`.

Comment: can you describe the steps to reproduce the error